# Burn .mkv to a .dvd for playback on DVD player while retaining multiple tracks?

Tags: conversion, subtitles, playback, mkv, tracks

If I use a program like ASVtoDVD or ConvertXToDVD to convert a .mkv to a .dvd, and the .mkv has multiple audio tracks/subtitle, will the produced .dvd only have one of those, or will it retain more or less everything the .mkv had? Also, how would I choose which is used if I'd use DVDFlick or ImgBurn to burn those to the disc once it's actually in the player? If you happen to know, while we're discussing ASVtoDVD/similar programs, can the convert .ogm files as well?

Comment: A lot of hardware dvd players can play mkv and mp4 files.  Are you sure you even need to make an actual Video DVD, rather than a data DVD with video files on it?

Comment: Also, just try it.  VLC can open a Video-DVD directory of VOB files, and probably also from an ISO.  If not, then mount the ISO, or extract the contents with 7-zip.